# How do you move a Visual Basic app to online, to display in a browser?

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser

Is it possible to move a .NET 4.5 Visual Basic app to an online form? If so what is the code required to display the app (other than the actual app code)?

Many thanks!

Comment: Sure... re-write all of the front-end code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but it requires work! Probably quite a lot of work.

Have you separated the UI into a separate layer? That will be the first job.

Is it a WinForms app? If so, look at [WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/what-is-web-forms). Microsoft invented WebForms to make it easier for WinForms programmers to create web apps. But there's [no trivial way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379130/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-winform-to-a-webform-in-net) to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597212/vb-net-easiest-way-to-export-convert-winform-app-to-web-asp-net-app) a WinForms app to a WebForms app.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/). Silverlight is like a flash, but even less compatible. Don't expect everything to work, because it probably won't and you will have to rewrite some things.  It depends what is your goal, but meybe it could just help you ;)

Comment: If it is a Forms app then basically nothing will convert.  And the Silverlight is not future.   MSFT is going to HTML5.   Still +1 so you don't think I am picking on you.